# Ubuntu wont recognize ASUS Transformer

Tags: android

I plug in my ASUS Transformer TF101 to my ASUS N43JM notebook computer running Ubuntu 11.10 64it but no USB device is recognized... not even that something "unknown" was plugged in. However it does recognize it in Windows 7...

Comment: can you use lsusb before and after plugging in the transformer and post those lines which were added when plugging in? can you short after plugging in invoke the dmesg command and post any error messages at the end of the output?

Comment: this might have to do with MTP or similar, but its not a conclusive answer and so won't post it as such

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer Joshua?